# SQL Update Query with select statement

Tags: sql

I have a table with email addresses. I am trying to fill a `DomainName` column with the domains from the email addresses. The select statement works fine on its own. But when I add it to the update query I get the following:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows `=`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What should I be using in place of the `=`?

```
update Table1 set Table1.DomainName=
(select SUBSTRING(Table1.Email,(CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email)+1),LEN(Table1.Email) - 
(CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email))) as DomainName FROM Table1)
```

Comment: try running your select query and see how many results it returns?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @marc_s Deja Vu all over again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the subselect.

```
update Table1 
set Table1.DomainName= SUBSTRING(Table1.Email,(CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email)+1),LEN(Table1.Email) - (CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email))) 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and made me feel dumb! Thank you Mr. Gregg and the others who replied with the same fix.

Comment: Don't feel bad.  You did all the heavy lifting.  Just needed a nudge to get across the finish line.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `SELECT` statement, it should be this way:

```
update Table1 
set Table1.DomainName= SUBSTRING(Table1.Email,
                                 (CHARINDEX('@', Table1.Email) + 1),
                                 LEN(Table1.Email) - (CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the subquery, this will work:

```
update Table1
set Table1.DomainName = SUBSTRING(Table1.Email,
    (CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email)+1),
    LEN(Table1.Email) - (CHARINDEX('@',Table1.Email)))
```